# Google apps script URL changes and does not open

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have an issue where other uses of my Google apps script's url is getting changed. Due to this issue they are not able to open the html page.

Original url "https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/s/abcxyz-kaskasdb/exec?v=applyleave"

changed url "https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcxyz-kaskasdb/exec?v=applyleave"

I realize "/a" and "/google.com" is getting removed some how.

How can I fix this issue.

Here is my code that is rendered:-

```
function include(filename)
{

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function render(file,argsObject){

var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
  
  if(argsObject){
    var keys = Object.keys(argsObject);
    keys.forEach(function(key){
      tmp[key] = argsObject[key];
    });
  }
 return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

And here's the code for the server which should accept POST requests:

```
var Route = {};
Route.path = function (route,callback){

  Route[route] = callback;
  
}

function doGet(e) {
  
  Route.path("applyleave",leaveApply)
  Route.path("leaveroster",leave_Roster)

  
 if (Route[e.parameters.v]){
   return Route[e.parameters.v]();}
  
   else {
     html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('home');

     
     return html.evaluate();
  
   
   }
}
```

The error received from other side is this :-

[image]

Can anyone explain and provide solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the deployment URL getting changed  - it is common for Google to perform this redirection.

The issue is can be rather a permission issue. Make sure you deploy the WebApp as "Anyone, even anonymous".

**However, currently I am experiencing the same behavior like you due to a multiply reported recent bug:**

https://issuetracker.google.com/72798634
https://issuetracker.google.com/165350842
https://issuetracker.google.com/166010550
https://issuetracker.google.com/166320373
https://issuetracker.google.com/167692852
https://issuetracker.google.com/169349069

Comment: I tried this but having same problem is there a way to keep my original url as same

Comment: See if signing out of multiple sessions solves the issue. try also incognito mode.

Comment: Interesting fact is other users are only using one gmail account. is there a way to manipulate url.

Comment: I believe that it is the opposite: `"https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcxyz-kaskasdb/exec` is the ORIGINAL url - you can verify it by going on `Deploy as web app -> Current web app URL`

Comment: I confirm 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/s/abcxyz-kaskasdb/exec?v=applyleave' is the origical URL

Comment: I do not know how you get this URL through manually copying the URL from `Deploy as web app -> Current web app URL`. Usually you obtain this URL after being redirected when pasting https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcxyz-kaskasdb/exec into the browser address bar.

Comment: Is there anything I can make the url as my original.

Comment: If you provide a user the URL of the type https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/s/abcxyz-kaskasdb/exec?v=applyleave - this URL likely contains your Google domain name, this is why users outside of the domain are not allowed to open this URL. This is why you need to provide users the URL of the type https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcxyz-kaskasdb/exec - when following this general URL - users will be automatically redirected correctly  - according to their account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224027/discussion-between-mask-and-ziganotschka).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43) Github repo.

After the first deployment, you need to make further deployments on the same version by clicking on "Manage Deployment" and then selecting the version to "New version"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICi4v.png)